# Wikipedia proof of Heine-Borel

Tags: general-topology

Is the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem in the Wikipedia article right? Aren't we assuming the conclusion when we apply Cantor's intersection theorem?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine-borel_theorem

Comment: This is also a WiKi only! You challenge a WiKi on a WiKi.

Comment: No. Cantor's theorem can be proved without any reference to compactness. For example, the proof I know uses only the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 4):

No, we aren't, since you can prove Cantor's intersection theorem particularly for $\Bbb R^n$ using it is complete. The proof for $\Bbb R$ generalizes to $\Bbb R^n$ immediately:

> **PROP** Let $a_n,b_n$ be bounded sequences for which $a_n\leq a_{n+1}\leq\dots\leq  b_{n+1}\leq b_n$. Let $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$. Then $$I=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}I_n$$ is nonempty.

**P** Show that $\sup \{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}=\lim a_n$ is in $I$.

> **COR** If $\lim a_n=\lim b_n$, $I$ consists of one point.

You might find this also stated in more generality as

> **PROP** Let $\langle K_n\rangle$ be a sequence of nonempty compact sets such that $$K_n\supseteq K_{n+1}$$ $$\operatorname{diam}K_n\to 0$$
>   Then $$K=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n$$ consists of one point.

Comment: I was not aware of this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the proof is circular. Instead, they should use some other proof that nested boxes have an intersection point (for instance using Cauchy sequences nd the definition of the reals in each coordinate).

Comment: No, it isn't, you can prove Cantor's intersection theorem particularly for $\Bbb R^n$ using it is complete.

Comment: True, but we're discussing the Wikipedia proofs, and the Wikipedia proof of Cantor's intersection theorem is proved using the finite sun over formulation of compactness.

Comment: Yes, but usually there is "Cantor's intersection theorem in $\Bbb R^n$" which we won't be silly enough to prove by compactness, if we want to use it to prove compactness.

Comment: Brian, it is true that if we limit yourselves to Wikipedia, then the proof is silly, so I will give you +1. I interpreted the question in a different way than you did.

Comment: Thanks! I +1ed yours because I hadn't seen it before.